# Adding/updating data to Parse.com using Javascript

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, updating

When using Parse, if I have an object called people and two columns, one called name and another called age. The user can input a name to match one that is already stored in Parse, and also input an age to be added to that specific name. How can I get it to search for the name the user has inputted, and if the name matches the user's input, add the age to that specific name?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot save anything in an object unless you have access to its objectId, therefore you need to perform a search as well as a save. You need to find the object(s) associated with the name the user enters and then add age value and save it. The code becomes something like:

```
var query = new Parse.Query("people");
query.equalTo("name", inputName);
query.find().then( function(objects) { // query and search for object(s)
    var person = objects[0]; // get the first object, there can be more than one obviously
    person.set("age", inputAge); // set the age
    return person.save(); // save the age value in object 
}).then(function() {
    // success
}, function(error) {
    // error
});
```

Comment: I tried this but I don't think the "var person = objects[0];" part is working because it gives me the error "Cannot read property 'set' of undefined".

Comment: This usually means that the query found no objects matching that name. The code snippet I wrote naively assumes it returns at least one object. You need to test objects.length property to see if it is greater than zero as before doing anything